# How does U-Boot get from this environment to booting Linux?

Tags: embedded

I'm trying to gain a root access to my ZTE F680 router. I already have a serial connection and able to interrupt the U-Boot autoboot. The problem I'm having is understanding how given the following environment, is U-Boot able to boot Linux whereas when I try to run the same commands in its shell it fails. The environment:

```
CASset=max
EMAC=EMAC0
MACMODE=GMII
MALLOC_len=5
MPmode=SMP
amp_enable=no
autoload=no
baudrate=115200
boot_order=hd_scr hd_img pxe net_img net_scr
bootargs_dflt=$console $mtdparts $bootargs_root nfsroot=$serverip:$rootpath ip=$ipaddr:$serverip$bootargs_end $mvNetConfig video=dovefb:lcd0:$lcd0_params clcd.lcd0_enable=$lcd0_enable clcd.lcd_panel=$lcd_panel
bootargs_end=:10.4.50.254:255.255.255.0:AvantaLP:eth0:none
bootargs_root=root=/dev/nfs rw
bootcmd=setenv bootargs console=ttyS0,115200 root=/dev/ram0 rw load_ramdisk=1 rdinit=/sbin/init mv_switch_config=none memsize=$(memsize) mem=$(memsize); bootm 0x2000100;
bootdelay=3
bootfile=uboot.bin
bootsize=0x60000
cacheShare=no
console=console=ttyS0,115200
device_partition=0:1
disL2Cache=yes
disL2Prefetch=yes
disaMvPnp=no
eeeEnable=no
enaClockGating=no
enaCpuStream=no
enaDCPref=yes
enaFPU=yes
enaICPref=yes
enaMonExt=no
enaWrAllo=no
eth1addr=00:50:43:00:02:02
eth1mtu=1500
eth2addr=00:50:43:00:00:02
eth2mtu=1500
eth3addr=00:50:43:02:00:00
eth3mtu=1500
ethact=egiga0
ethaddr=00:50:43:00:02:02
ethmtu=1500
ethprime=egiga0
fdt_addr=2040000
flashsize=134217728
fullfile=upgrade.bin
ide_path=/
image_name=uImage
initrd_name=uInitrd
ipaddr=192.168.1.1
kernel_addr_r=2080000
kernelsize=0x16000000
lcd0_enable=0
lcd0_params=640x480-16@60
lcd_panel=0
linuzfile=vmlinuz.bin
loadaddr=0x02000000
loads_echo=0
memsize=253M
mtddevname=boot
mtddevnum=0
mtdids=nand0=mvebu-nand
mtdparts=mtdparts=mvebu-nand:1536k@0(boot),512k(env),20m(kernel0),20m(kernel1),6m(others),4m(parameter),8m(usercfg),4m(middleware),4m(wlan)
mvNetConfig=mv_switch_config=none
mv_pon_addr=00:50:43:02:00:00
nandEcc=1bit
nand_erasesize=20000
nand_oobsize=40
nand_writesize=800
netbsd_en=no
netdev=mii0
netmask=255.255.255.0
netretry=no
partition=nand0,0
pcieTune=no
pexMode=RC
pxe_files_load=:default.arm-armadaxp-db:default.arm-armadaxp:default.arm
pxefile_addr_r=3100000
ramdisk_addr_r=2880000
rcvr_image=rootfs.squashfs.rcvr.img
rootfile=rootfs.img
rootpath=/srv/nfs/
sata_delay_reset=0
sata_dma_mode=yes
script_addr_r=3000000
script_name=boot.scr
serverip=192.168.1.100
setL2CacheWT=no
silent=0
standalone=fsload 0x2000000 $image_name;setenv bootargs $console $mtdparts root=/dev/mtdblock0 rw ip=$ipaddr:$serverip$bootargs_end; bootm 0x2000000;
stderr=serial
stdin=serial
stdout=serial
versioninfo=U-Boot V2.0.10T5 0x1600000 0x1 0x82 0x87
vxworks_en=no
yuk_ethaddr=00:00:00:EE:51:81

Environment size: 2586/131068 bytes
```

From what I gatered, the [stage 2](https://github.com/umiddelb/armhf/wiki/Get-more-out-of-%22Das-U-Boot%22#stage-2-u-boot) should load the `boot.scr` script and then execute `bootcmd`. But trying to do this in shell fails. Trying to run `boot.scr` claims there's no valid image at this address and loading it with `fsload` fails with:

```
### JFFS2 loading 'boot.scr' to 0x3000000
Scanning JFFS2 FS:  done.
find_inode failed for name=boot.scr
load: Failed to find inode
```

The partition table does exist:

```
=> mtdparts
mtdparts

device nand0 <mvebu-nand>, # parts = 9
 #: name        size        offset      mask_flags
 0: boot                0x000000180000      0x000000000000      0
 1: env                 0x000000080000      0x000000180000      0
 2: kernel0             0x000001400000      0x000000200000      0
 3: kernel1             0x000001400000      0x000001600000      0
 4: others              0x000000600000      0x000002a00000      0
 5: parameter           0x000000400000      0x000003000000      0
 6: usercfg             0x000000800000      0x000003400000      0
 7: middleware          0x000000400000      0x000003c00000      0
 8: wlan                0x000000400000      0x000004000000      0
```

but listing any of them with `ls` gives no results:

```
=> ls
Scanning JFFS2 FS:  done.
```

I'm wondering if maybe U-Boot has been compiled without some commands (i.e. `fdt` command is missing) or some hardcoded boot sequence? If I don't interrupt the autoboot it looks like this:

```
Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0
flash block_size is 0x20000
flash size(search addredd) is 0x8000000
search.c,372,do_search: search->result[index].entry = 0x200100
search.c,372,do_search: search->result[index].entry = 0x1600100
do_search ending
do_startup() start
select=0x1
search->result[select].entry=1600100
search->result[1].entry = 0x1600100
do_startup() ending
do_settings() start
do_setting versioninfo
btNumbers is V2.0.10T5
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 02000100 ...
   Image Name:   Linux Kernel Image
   Created:      2017-10-25   9:10:20 UTC
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (gzip compressed)
   Data Size:    15128571 Bytes = 14.4 MiB
   Load Address: 00008000
   Entry Point:  00008000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
   Uncompressing Kernel Image ... OK
|-->setup versioninfo tag...versioninfo is U-Boot V2.0.10T5 0x1600000 0x1 0x82 0x87

Starting kernel ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost two years later I had to do it again and this time I documented my process!
Looks like U-Boot has a script (probably custom for ZTE) that scans the NAND memory in search for an image and then loads it in memory. This part is visible in logs here:

```
search.c,372,do_search: search->result[index].entry = 0x200100
search.c,372,do_search: search->result[index].entry = 0x1600100
do_search ending
do_startup() start
select=0x1
search->result[select].entry=1600100
search->result[1].entry = 0x1600100
do_startup() ending
```

I'm not sure how I can call this script but I managed to load the image manually. First I took note of the addresses: image in flash:

```
search->result[select].entry=1600100
```

and memory where it's jumped to:

```
## Booting kernel from Legacy Image at 02000100 ...
```

As loading has to be aligned with the page, I ended up loading from `0x1600000` into `0x2000000`. Only missing part was the size for the [`nand load`](https://www.denx.de/wiki/view/DULG/UBootCmdGroupNand) command but I assumed the whole partition would be enough so I just took the value from `mtdparts` command and ended up with:

```
> nand read 0x2000000 0x1600000 0x1400000
```

Now with the image loaded I could just `run bootcmd` but I wanted to gain root access so I made a small tweak to the `bootargs` by adding `single` to boot it in single user mode:

```
> setenv bootargs console=ttyS0,115200 root=/dev/ram0 rw load_ramdisk=1 rdinit=/sbin/init mv_switch_config=none memsize=$(memsize) mem=$(memsize) single
> bootm 0x2000100
```

I hope this answer is useful for the two people who upvoted this question and for any [future visitor](https://xkcd.com/979/).